# divide a ring drawable into two equal part in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

i want to have a half drawable ring just like an arc.
i have a code that just creates the ring but i am confused how to make it a half ring.
how do i achieve this half ring drawable?

```
<shape android:shape="ring"
    android:innerRadius="15dp"
    android:thickness="20dp"
    android:useLevel="false"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="@color/blue"/>
    <size android:height="200dp" android:width="200dp"/>
</shape>
```

This is the image that exactly looks like what am trying to achieve.
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XHlr.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can create like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:end="0dp"
        android:left="-500dp">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="500dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:end="100dp"
        android:bottom="100dp"
        android:top="100dp"
        android:start="-400dp">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="500dp" />
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

if you went to perfect view then create svg file for this